# Dimension of closure in Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I study Hilbert spaces and I have a question about dimension. If $G$ is a subspace of Hilbert space $H$. What is the relationship between $\text{dim}(G)$ and $\text{dim}(\text{cl}(G))$?

Comment: Any finite dimensional subspace is closed.

Comment: If $G$ is finite dimensional, then $G$ is already closed.  If $G$ has countable dimension, then the dimension of $\overline{G}$ has strictly greater cardinality, because an infinite dimensional complete normed space must have uncountable dimension.  If $G$ already has uncountable dimension, I am not sure what happens, let me think about it.